# Scanner not returning to choice menu and single variable not initialized in Java

Tags: java

After picking option `3` and providing required data, my code doesn't return to `switch` menu.
It crashes with `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException` error.

There is also other issue, `productId` throws `variable might not have been initialized` error which is odd since `deliveryAddress` gets initialized with no issues.

Thanks in advance for guidance.

**user**

```
package com.apporders;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Scanner;

// make user use Entity abstract class and modify it's method to show only System.out.println(System.getenv().get("USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE"));
public class user {
    
    //Private access modifier
    private String name;

    //getter
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    //setter
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> userActivity() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //ArrayList
        ArrayList<String> activity = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("Provide data");
        activity.add(input.next());

        input.close();
        return activity;
    }
}
```

**panel**

```
public class panel implements Imeta{
    
    //Proteted access modifier
    protected void welcomeMsg() {
        System.out.println("Please log in");
    }
}

//Inheritance
class rootPanel extends panel{
    
    //polymorphism by overriding
    @Override
    protected void welcomeMsg() {
        System.out.println("Root logged in, please bare in mind that you are ROOT!");
    }
 }
```

**dataBaseConnection**

```
package com.apporders;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.bson.Document;

import com.mongodb.MongoException;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class dataBaseConnection {

    private String url = "";

    String getUrl() {
        return this.url;
    }

    public MongoClient establishDbConnection() {

        Logger.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
        dataBaseConnection dbLink = new dataBaseConnection();

        try {
            MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(dbLink.getUrl());
            System.out.println("---------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Connected successfully to server.");
            System.out.println("---------------------------------");

            return mongoClient;

        } catch (MongoException e) {
            System.out.println("---------------------------------");
            System.err.println("An error occurred while attempting to connect: " + e);
            System.out.println("---------------------------------");
            }
        
        return null;

    }

    public void insertData(String user, Duration sessionLength, MongoClient mongoClient, ArrayList<String> productId, ArrayList<String> deliveryAddress) {

        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("gettingStarted");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("people");
        

        Map<String, Object> metaData = new HashMap<>();
        metaData.put("meta_one", "xyz");
        metaData.put("meta_two", "abc");

        collection.insertOne(new Document()
                        .append("_id", new ObjectId())
                        .append("user", user)
                        .append("session length (seconds)", sessionLength.toSeconds())
                        .append("meta_data", metaData)
                        .append("productId", productId)
                        .append("deliveryAddress", deliveryAddress)
        );

        mongoClient.close();
    }
}
```

**App**

```
public class App 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean openSession = true;
        panel welcomePanel = new panel();
        user userName = new user();

        System.out.println(welcomePanel.showMetaData());

        welcomePanel.welcomeMsg();
        userName.setName(scanner.next());

        System.out.println("user logged: " + userName.getName());

        if (userName.getName().equals("Root")) {
            rootPanel rootMsg = new rootPanel();
            rootMsg.welcomeMsg();
        }

        while(openSession) {
            Instant start = Instant.now();
            System.out.println("Session has been opened");
            System.out.println("1. Exit");
            System.out.println("2. Place item ID you are ordering");
            System.out.println("3. Place delivery addres");

            int userPick = scanner.nextInt(); 

            switch (userPick) {
                case 1: openSession = false;
                scanner.close();
                    
                case 2: openSession = false;
                ArrayList<String> productId = userName.userActivity();

                case 3: openSession = false;
                ArrayList<String> deliveryAddress = userName.userActivity();
                userPick = scanner.nextInt();


                Instant end = Instant.now();
                Duration sessionLength = Duration.between(start, end);
                System.out.println("Session time in seconds: " + sessionLength.getSeconds());
                    
                dataBaseConnection connection = new dataBaseConnection();
                    
                try {
                    connection.insertData(
                        userName.getName(),
                        sessionLength,
                        connection.establishDbConnection(),
                        productId, //this thorws "variable might not have been initialized", why?
                        deliveryAddress
                    );

                }

                catch (MongoTimeoutException e) {
                    System.err.println("Timeout error: "+ e);
                    }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, your code doesn't compile, as there are no types such as `user`, `panel` or `dataBaseConnection` provided. Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise we can't debug the code. Second, `productId`, the variable you're asking question about, is commented out. Should it be like that? Please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77382786/edit) the question and provide more clarity to it.

Comment: I will update code repo, `productId` is commented out for the time being.

Comment: Provide the code as it is when the problem occurs, so that we can reproduce it.

Comment: Ok, I added missing parts of the code and brought back `productId`.

Comment: Checking, one second.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255781/discussion-between-marcin2x4-and-giorgi-tsiklauri).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't start the names of your types (interface, class, enum) with a lowercase letter, i.e. `product` class should be `Product` and so on, for every other type. This is a [Java Naming Convention](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) and it's pretty important.

---

Question #1 about exception:

You're adding `String` with `input.next()` invocation (in `userActivity` method), but then you're trying to read an `int` with `.nextInt()`, in `case 3` of switch statement. Sure, there is `NoSuchElementException` as there is no `int` there.

---

Question #2 about variable initialization:

> *this thorws "variable might not have been initialized", why?*

Because you define this variable in one branch of the `switch` and you're accessing/using it in another. What happens if case `3` is matched? variable `productId` will never be initialized. Maybe you should define it in a bit wider/outer scope, like outside (and before) the `switch`?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `openSession` to `false` at the beginning of every `case` and your `while` loop rightfully stops. Also, you forgot about `break` statements in your `switch`. [More](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) about switch in Java.

Overall, there are several issues in your code.

- `start` should be initialized before the loop
- `productId` and `deliveryAddress` must be declared before the loop
- The whole order placing logic should be a separate choice, because right now it executes when you select `3` and `productId` might not be initialized yet.

You probably want something closer to this:

```
        Instant start = Instant.now();
        ArrayList<String> productId = null;
        ArrayList<String> deliveryAddress = null;
        System.out.println("Session has been opened");
        while (openSession) {
            System.out.println("1. Exit");
            System.out.println("2. Place item ID you are ordering");
            System.out.println("3. Place delivery address");
            System.out.println("4. Process order");
            int userPick = scanner.nextInt();

            switch (userPick) {
                case 1:
                    openSession = false;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    productId = /*init productId*/;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    deliveryAddress = /*init deliveryAddress*/;
                    break;

                case 4:
                    if (deliveryAddress == null) {
                        System.out.println("Place delivery address first");
                        break;
                    }
                    if (productId == null) {
                        System.out.println("Place item ID first");
                        break;
                    }
                    // Do the business logic, set openSession to false?
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Incorrect choice");
                    break;
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
```